# setOnClickListener in fragment

Tags: android

I have simple application which has 1 Edittext and 1 Button.My application get the numbers in the first two Edit text and when the button is pressed the last EditText show the sum of the first Two EditText.Until now, I have done all this with Activity, but I want to do this with fragment.I have [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer) source code, that have navigation Drawer, andwhen try to do the same in this code I have problems with setOnClicklistener

This is my code:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    EditText Num1, Num2, Eq;
    Button Sum;
    int S;

    public FindPeopleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        View InputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
        Num1 = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Num1);
        Num2 = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Num2);
        Eq = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Eq);
        Sum = (Button) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Sum);

        Sum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                String N1 = Num1.getText().toString();
                int N11 = Integer.parseInt(N1);

                String N2 = Num2.getText().toString();
                int N22 = Integer.parseInt(N2);

                S = N11 + N22;

                Eq.setText("" + S);

            }
        });

        return InputFragmentView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {
EditText Num1, Num2, Eq;
Button Sum;
int S;

public FindPeopleFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View InputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_find_people, container, false);
    Num1 = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Num1);
    Num2 = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Num2);
    Eq = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Eq);
    Sum = (Button) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Sum);
    ;

    Sum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String N1 = Num1.getText().toString();
            int N11 = Integer.parseInt(N1);

            String N2 = Num2.getText().toString();
            int N22 = Integer.parseInt(N2);

            S = N11 + N22;

            Eq.setText("" + S);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "your Sum is : " + S,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return InputFragmentView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
Sum = (Button) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Sum);

Sum.setOnClickListener(this);

return InputFragmentView;
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.Sum:
            String N1 = Num1.getText().toString();
            int N11 = Integer.parseInt(N1);

            String N2 = Num2.getText().toString();
            int N22 = Integer.parseInt(N2);

            S = N11 + N22;

            Eq.setText("" + S);
            break;
    }
}
```

Anyway, post your Logcat output to know which is the problem you are facing

Comment: i have this error :
The type FindPeopleFragment must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)

in this line :
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

and this error :
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (FindPeopleFragment)

in this line :
Sum.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: 1st check your inports. Delete the import refering to the onClickListener and add it again without "DialogInterface". 2nd try to put the code the way I've done it above

Answer (score 0):

Or just leave it like this, but remove the implementation of OnClickListener.
ex:
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
...
}